# Woocommerce single product image blurred and small. Actual image is big

Tags: themes, plugins, bug

The image in the woocommerce's product page is blurred and unclear. You can see this using the below link.

http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/shop/discipline-your-kid-the-right-way-without-shouting-or-spanking/

I tried changing the CSS and regenerated the thumbnails, after changing the image dimensions in catalog settings of woocommerce but this persists.

This issue is weird. I think the issue is in product-image.php file of woocommerce which is returning small, thumbnail size image instead of the medium one. Here is the code that returns the image.

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters('single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
$image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
$attachment_count   = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The actual image is not big: http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/discipline-right-way-e1375128137307.jpg

Comment: What is `shop_single`?

Comment: I am not sure what is shop_single. This could probably have info about the size. I don't know where it is defined in woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @JMau is referring to the following:

[image]

The actual image is only 211px wide, it displays at 281px wide, therefore pixelation is occurring.

The bigger issue here is that the little thumbnail image displaying to the left of the main product image is throwing the alignment off. Add the following to your custom CSS styles to fix the alignment:

```
.single-product.woocommerce .product .avatar {
width: 10%;
}
.single-product.woocommerce .product .avatar img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.single-product.woocommerce .product .images {
width: 37%;
}
```

This will result in everything fitting on the same row, rather than having the title/price/add-to-cart button shifted underneath the image, like so:

[image]

This also results in the main product image consistently displaying at 217px wide (I see it varies across your products currently) and will also reduce the pixelation a bit on your example link, as now the difference will be only 6px rather than 70px.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the s[ource file](http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/discipline-right-way-e1375128137307.jpg), you're trying to display a small image at large scale that's the reason why you get this blur.

You have to upload another source image (larger and taller)  and maybe regenerate thumbnails.

Comment: I did look the source file. The code snippet pasted above is from that file itself. I tried uploading the original file and regenerated thumbnails but nothing worked.